# PHP cURL Response Header

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying out HTTP Requests for the first time (also using PostMan). There, everything works fine. When exporting it with PHP cURL I get the following:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "htt..",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic ..."
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

I am expecting a Key in the response Header, So I'm trying to get the Response Header as a variable (pref. Array). How would I do this? I got no luck so far trying to use the following:

```
$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

**Edit 1:**

Using https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ I converted the Postman cURL command to PHP cURL (instead of using Postman's generator) and got the following, which seems to work:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'htt..');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); //manually added
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); //manually added
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //manually added

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic ...';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($result, $header_size);

curl_close($ch);
echo $header;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your'e really close to solving this, but you need to set the `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true to retrieve the headers. This change should work:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "htt..",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true, 
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic ..."
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl) !== CURLE_OK) {
    throw new \RuntimeException("curl_exec error: " . curl_error($ch) . ": " . curl_error($ch));
}

$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that and I seem to still get 0 on Header_Size.

Comment: @Wrsn this code should work. the only thing this code lacks is header=>array parsing and error checking. if you get 0 headers from this code, it means there's a curl exec error, and because this code is lacking error checking, the error isn't detected. try adding ```$response = curl_exec($curl); if(curl_errno($curl)!==CURLE_OK){throw new \RuntimeException("curl_exec error: ".curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch));}``` - it should throw an exception explaining what happened.

Answer (score 0):

$response is always only response body.

Try to look at option for curl_getinfo

```
CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT - The request string sent. For this to work, add the CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT option to the handle by calling curl_setopt()
```

Here is the documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: Using: 
$test = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
echo $test;

I see that i'm getting null.

with CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT I get 0 as a response. So may it be that I may not even getting a response at all? (with a normal non-php cURL call in unix on the system I get the expected response)

Comment: Have you add CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true to curl_setopt_array?

Comment: Yes, Tried that. Sadly same result :/

Comment: sorry but this will fetch your own REQUEST headers, not the RESPONSE headers, but @Wrsn want the RESPONSE headers, not the REQUEST headers.